# Matching string in F# FAKE build file

Tags: build, f#, f#-fake

I have a F# FAKE build file that I want to call with a parameter `conf` that can have two values, cs and sk. My batch file looks like this

```
@echo off
cls
"tools\nuget\nuget.exe" "install" "FAKE" "-OutputDirectory" "tools" "-ExcludeVersion"
"tools\FAKE\tools\Fake.exe" build.fsx conf=sk
pause
```

In the F# file, I get the parameter using `environVar "conf"` and this works ok.

Now I want to create a helper methof in the F# file that matches the `conf` parameters and returns a string (build configuration value in my case), so I have

```
let getConfiguration conf =
   if (conf=="cs") then "Release"
   else "Release(SK)"
```

I get a strange message

```
build.fsx(29,71): error FS0001: The type 'string' does not support the operator '=='
```

This is how I use the method

```
Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    !! @"**/*.csproj"
      |> MSBuild buildDir "Build" ["Configuration",(getConfiguration (environVar "conf"))]
      |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
)
```

Comment: you also don't need brackets around `conf = "cs"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F# equality operator is `=`.

I don't know FAKE or whether your approach will work, but the reason for the compiler error is that, as the error message states, there is no `==` operator. Valid version:

```
    if conf = "cs" then "Release" else "Release(SK)"
```

See e.g. the [symbol and operator reference in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx).